# ViewPager2 - Is there an alternative to PagerTitleStrip?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

Is it possible to create something similar to the PagerTitleStrip that existed in ViewPager? My intention is to just display titles for the fragments that are added without having a tabLayout.

Comment: ViewPager2 was updated today. No mention of PagerTabStrip yet. Hope they will provide a solution.